# how to get the selected item in a connected listviewer web part using javascript in sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010

I have a set of connected web part on a page. Basically these are out of the box webparts and are connected. The provider and consumer are connected on the user name field (donmain\userName). So selecting a value from the provider webpart updates all the consumer web parts data.

Now my question, I would like to get the selected item from the webpart, the selected item has a "img" tag whose "alt" text is "Selected" so based on this I would like to get the selected text of the next elemet.

This is my Mark UP and from the markup I would like the value"domain\test.officer" returned as it is the selected item.

```
            <TABLE id={2E5002B0-EDC3-4541-A0ED-2A81797B459C}-{F1162455-D63E-481D-B13C-C1A4A59E5A34} class=ms-listviewtable border=0 cellSpacing=0 summary="Trainee " cellPadding=1 width="100%" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" o:WebQuerySourceHref="http://test.app.domain.net/test/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=65001&amp;XMLDATA=1&amp;RowLimit=0&amp;View={F1162455-D63E-481D-B13C-C1A4A59E5A34}" handleDeleteInit="true"><TBODY>
            <TR class="ms-viewheadertr ms-vhltr" vAlign=top>
            <TH class=ms-vh-icon scope=col><INPUT class=s4-selectAllCbx title="Select or deselect all items" onclick=ToggleAllItems(event,this,159) value="" type=checkbox></TH>
            <TH class=ms-vh2 onmouseover=OnChildColumn(this) scope=col noWrap>
            <DIV class=ms-vh-div name="SelectTitle" SortFields="View={f1162455-d63e-481d-b13c-c1a4a59e5a34}&amp;SortField=SelectTitle&amp;SortDir=Asc" ResultType="" FieldType="Computed" DisplayName="Select" CTXNum="159" FilterDisableMessage="" Filterable="FALSE" FilterDisable="" SortDisable="" Sortable="FALSE">Select</DIV></TH>
            <TH class=ms-vh-icon onmouseover=OnChildColumn(this) scope=col noWrap>
            <DIV class=ms-vh-div name="Attachments" SortFields="View={f1162455-d63e-481d-b13c-c1a4a59e5a34}&amp;SortField=Attachments&amp;SortDir=Asc" ResultType="" FieldType="Attachments" DisplayName="Attachments" CTXNum="159" FilterDisableMessage="" Filterable="" FilterDisable="" SortDisable="" Sortable=""><A id=diidSortAttachments onfocus=OnFocusFilter(this) onclick="javascript:return OnClickFilter(this,event);" href="javascript: " SortingFields="View={f1162455-d63e-481d-b13c-c1a4a59e5a34}&amp;SortField=Attachments&amp;SortDir=Asc"><IMG border=0 src="/_layouts/images/attachhd.gif"><IMG class=ms-hidden border=0 alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)." src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width=1 height=1></A><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"></DIV>
            <DIV class=s4-ctx><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN><A onfocus="OnChildColumn(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" title="Open Menu" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;"></A><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></DIV></TH>
            <TH class=ms-vh2 onmouseover=OnChildColumn(this) scope=col noWrap>
            <DIV class=ms-vh-div name="LinkTitle" SortFields="View={f1162455-d63e-481d-b13c-c1a4a59e5a34}&amp;SortField=LinkTitle&amp;SortDir=Asc" ResultType="" FieldType="Computed" DisplayName="Title" CTXNum="159" FilterDisableMessage="" Filterable="" FilterDisable="" SortDisable="" Sortable=""><A id=diidSortLinkTitle onfocus=OnFocusFilter(this) onclick="javascript:return OnClickFilter(this,event);" href="javascript: " SortingFields="View={f1162455-d63e-481d-b13c-c1a4a59e5a34}&amp;SortField=LinkTitle&amp;SortDir=Asc">Title<IMG class=ms-hidden border=0 alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)." src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width=1 height=1></A><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"><IMG border=0 alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"></DIV>
            <DIV class=s4-ctx><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN><A onfocus="OnChildColumn(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" title="Open Menu" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;"></A><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></DIV></TH></TR>
            <TR class=ms-itmhover iid="159,9,0" setEdgeBorder="true">
            <TD class="ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-firstCell"><INPUT class=s4-itm-cbx title="domain\test.user1&#13;&#10;  " value="" type=checkbox _setup="true"></TD>
            <TD class=ms-vb2><IMG style="CURSOR: hand" border=0 alt=Selected align=absMiddle src="/_layouts/images/rbsel.gif"></TD>
            <TD class=ms-vb2></TD>
            <TD class="ms-vb-title ms-vb-lastCell" onmouseover=OnChildItem(this) height="100%">
            <DIV id=9 class="ms-vb itx" onmouseover=OnItem(this) EventType="" Perm="0x7fffffffffffffff" Field="LinkTitle" CTXName="ctx159"><A onfocus=OnLink(this) onclick="EditLink2(this,159);return false;" href="http://test.app.domain.net/test/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={2E5002B0-EDC3-4541-A0ED-2A81797B459C}&amp;ID=9&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0100801F054C4E00C243A9A49EC13FF778D7003293EF8DE37E144BAA8A5296D5E6CA8B" target=_self>domain\test.user1</A><IMG class=ms-newgif title=New alt=New src="/_layouts/1033/images/new.gif"></DIV>
            <DIV class=s4-ctx onmouseover="OnChildItem(this.parentNode); return false;"><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN><A onfocus="OnChildItem(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" title="Open Menu" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;"></A><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></DIV></TD></TR>
            <TR class="ms-alternating ms-itmhover" iid="159,8,0" setEdgeBorder="true">
            <TD class="ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-firstCell"><INPUT class=s4-itm-cbx title="domain\test.officer&#13;&#10;  " value="" type=checkbox _setup="true"></TD>
            <TD class=ms-vb2><A onclick="SelectField('{F1162455-D63E-481D-B13C-C1A4A59E5A34}','8');return false;" href="javascript:SelectField('{F1162455-D63E-481D-B13C-C1A4A59E5A34}','8');return false;" target=_self><IMG style="CURSOR: hand" border=0 alt=Normal align=absMiddle src="/_layouts/images/rbunsel.gif"></A></TD>
            <TD class=ms-vb2></TD>
            <TD class="ms-vb-title ms-vb-lastCell" onmouseover=OnChildItem(this) height="100%">
            <DIV id=8 class="ms-vb itx" onmouseover=OnItem(this) EventType="" Perm="0x7fffffffffffffff" Field="LinkTitle" CTXName="ctx159"><A onfocus=OnLink(this) onclick="EditLink2(this,159);return false;" href="http://test.app.domain.net/test/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={2E5002B0-EDC3-4541-A0ED-2A81797B459C}&amp;ID=8&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0100801F054C4E00C243A9A49EC13FF778D7003293EF8DE37E144BAA8A5296D5E6CA8B" target=_self>domain\test.officer</A><IMG class=ms-newgif title=New alt=New src="/_layouts/1033/images/new.gif"></DIV>
            <DIV class=s4-ctx onmouseover="OnChildItem(this.parentNode); return false;"><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN><A onfocus="OnChildItem(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" title="Open Menu" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;"></A><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></DIV></TD></TR>
            <TR class=ms-itmhover iid="159,5,0" setEdgeBorder="true">
            <TD class="ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-firstCell"><INPUT class=s4-itm-cbx title="domain\n.test&#13;&#10;  " value="" type=checkbox _setup="true"></TD>
            <TD class=ms-vb2><A onclick="SelectField('{F1162455-D63E-481D-B13C-C1A4A59E5A34}','5');return false;" href="javascript:SelectField('{F1162455-D63E-481D-B13C-C1A4A59E5A34}','5');return false;" target=_self><IMG style="CURSOR: hand" border=0 alt=Normal align=absMiddle src="/_layouts/images/rbunsel.gif"></A></TD>
            <TD class=ms-vb2></TD>
            <TD class="ms-vb-title ms-vb-lastCell" onmouseover=OnChildItem(this) height="100%">
            <DIV id=5 class="ms-vb itx" onmouseover=OnItem(this) EventType="" Perm="0x7fffffffffffffff" Field="LinkTitle" CTXName="ctx159"><A onfocus=OnLink(this) onclick="EditLink2(this,159);return false;" href="http://test.app.domain.net/test/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={2E5002B0-EDC3-4541-A0ED-2A81797B459C}&amp;ID=5&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0100801F054C4E00C243A9A49EC13FF778D7003293EF8DE37E144BAA8A5296D5E6CA8B" target=_self>domain\n.test</A><IMG class=ms-newgif title=New alt=New src="/_layouts/1033/images/new.gif"></DIV>
            <DIV class=s4-ctx onmouseover="OnChildItem(this.parentNode); return false;"><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN><A onfocus="OnChildItem(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" title="Open Menu" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;"></A><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></DIV></TD></TR>
            <TR class="ms-alternating ms-itmhover" iid="159,3,0" setEdgeBorder="true">
            <TD class="ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-firstCell"><INPUT class=s4-itm-cbx title="domain\test1.user1&#13;&#10;  " value="" type=checkbox _setup="true"></TD>
            <TD class=ms-vb2><A onclick="SelectField('{F1162455-D63E-481D-B13C-C1A4A59E5A34}','3');return false;" href="javascript:SelectField('{F1162455-D63E-481D-B13C-C1A4A59E5A34}','3');return false;" target=_self><IMG style="CURSOR: hand" border=0 alt=Normal align=absMiddle src="/_layouts/images/rbunsel.gif"></A></TD>
            <TD class=ms-vb2></TD>
            <TD class="ms-vb-title ms-vb-lastCell" onmouseover=OnChildItem(this) height="100%">
            <DIV id=3 class="ms-vb itx" onmouseover=OnItem(this) EventType="" Perm="0x7fffffffffffffff" Field="LinkTitle" CTXName="ctx159"><A onfocus=OnLink(this) onclick="EditLink2(this,159);return false;" href="http://test.app.domain.net/test/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={2E5002B0-EDC3-4541-A0ED-2A81797B459C}&amp;ID=3&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0100801F054C4E00C243A9A49EC13FF778D7003293EF8DE37E144BAA8A5296D5E6CA8B" target=_self>domain\test1.user1</A><IMG class=ms-newgif title=New alt=New src="/_layouts/1033/images/new.gif"></DIV>
            <DIV class=s4-ctx onmouseover="OnChildItem(this.parentNode); return false;"><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN><A onfocus="OnChildItem(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" title="Open Menu" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;"></A><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></DIV></TD></TR>
            <TR class=ms-itmhover iid="159,2,0" setEdgeBorder="true">
            <TD class="ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-firstCell"><INPUT class=s4-itm-cbx title="domain\admin.user&#13;&#10;  " value="" type=checkbox _setup="true"></TD>
            <TD class=ms-vb2><A onclick="SelectField('{F1162455-D63E-481D-B13C-C1A4A59E5A34}','2');return false;" href="javascript:SelectField('{F1162455-D63E-481D-B13C-C1A4A59E5A34}','2');return false;" target=_self><IMG style="CURSOR: hand" border=0 alt=Normal align=absMiddle src="/_layouts/images/rbunsel.gif"></A></TD>
            <TD class=ms-vb2></TD>
            <TD class="ms-vb-title ms-vb-lastCell" onmouseover=OnChildItem(this) height="100%">
            <DIV id=2 class="ms-vb itx" onmouseover=OnItem(this) EventType="" Perm="0x7fffffffffffffff" Field="LinkTitle" CTXName="ctx159"><A onfocus=OnLink(this) onclick="EditLink2(this,159);return false;" href="http://test.app.domain.net/test/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={2E5002B0-EDC3-4541-A0ED-2A81797B459C}&amp;ID=2&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0100801F054C4E00C243A9A49EC13FF778D7003293EF8DE37E144BAA8A5296D5E6CA8B" target=_self>domain\admin.user</A></DIV>
            <DIV class=s4-ctx onmouseover="OnChildItem(this.parentNode); return false;"><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN><A onfocus="OnChildItem(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" title="Open Menu" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;"></A><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></DIV></TD></TR>
            <TR class="ms-alternating ms-itmhover" iid="159,1,0" setEdgeBorder="true">
            <TD class="ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-firstCell"><INPUT class=s4-itm-cbx title="domain\portal.user&#13;&#10;  " value="" type=checkbox _setup="true"></TD>
            <TD class=ms-vb2><A onclick="SelectField('{F1162455-D63E-481D-B13C-C1A4A59E5A34}','1');return false;" href="javascript:SelectField('{F1162455-D63E-481D-B13C-C1A4A59E5A34}','1');return false;" target=_self><IMG style="CURSOR: hand" border=0 alt=Normal align=absMiddle src="/_layouts/images/rbunsel.gif"></A></TD>
            <TD class=ms-vb2></TD>
            <TD class="ms-vb-title ms-vb-lastCell" onmouseover=OnChildItem(this) height="100%">
            <DIV id=1 class="ms-vb itx" onmouseover=OnItem(this) EventType="" Perm="0x7fffffffffffffff" Field="LinkTitle" CTXName="ctx159"><A onfocus=OnLink(this) onclick="EditLink2(this,159);return false;" href="http://test.app.domain.net/test/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&amp;ListId={2E5002B0-EDC3-4541-A0ED-2A81797B459C}&amp;ID=1&amp;ContentTypeID=0x0100801F054C4E00C243A9A49EC13FF778D7003293EF8DE37E144BAA8A5296D5E6CA8B" target=_self>domain\portal.user</A></DIV>
            <DIV class=s4-ctx onmouseover="OnChildItem(this.parentNode); return false;"><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN><A onfocus="OnChildItem(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" title="Open Menu" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;"></A><SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model method "[SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff409526.aspx)" to obtain the selected items.

Try this script in Content Editor Webpart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function ShowSelectedItems() {
  var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
  var key;
  for (key in selectedItems) {
   alert(selectedItems[key].id);
  }


 }</script>
 <input name="btnShowSelectedItems" id="btnShowSelectedItems" onclick="ShowSelectedItems();" type="button" value="Show Selected Items"/>
```

I will not recommend this, but if you really wanna go jQuery with this you can probably try this script:

```
var selectedImg$ = $('img[alt^="Selected"]');
var elemID = selectedImg$.closest('tr').attr('iid').split(',')[1];
var linkText = selectedImg$.closest('tr').find('div#'+elemID).find('a').text();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply, the jQuery method is exactly what I was looking for :) (I do not have enough points to mark the answer as useful, sorry)

Comment: Just to point out to those who might get here via google, these approaches are for different things. The first gets items selected with checkboxes, the second gets items selected with the "connected webparts" selection. (default icon is a double headed arrow pointing diagonally).